# Ubuntu Server VM (Hyper-V): formatting of sda2 partition (mkfs.ext4 -G 4096 /dev/sda2) before install

Tags: server, partitioning, filesystem, ext4, hyper-v

I'm venturing into the fascinating world of Ubuntu and would like to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS as a virtual machine in Hyper-V.

Microsoft recommends that, when creating the file system on which Ubuntu will be installed, the number of block groups that will be packed together to create a larger virtual block group (or "flex_bg group") in an ext4 filesystem should be set to 4096 (mkfs.ext4 -G 4096 /dev/sdX1)

When installing the Ubuntu Server VM, I didn't see an option to set this parameter.

After having installed Ubuntu Server with the default options, I have the following partitions:

```
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 42.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      538MB   42.9GB  42.4GB  ext4
```

When running

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda2
```

I see that the number of block groups for sda2 is 16:

```
Flex block group size:    16
```

Is there a way to set this to 4096 during install?

If not, could I repartition sda2 with the correct number of block groups (with which tool (e.g. mounted in a (virtual) DVD drive?)) and then reinstall selecting manually the sda1 and sda2 partitions?

Comment: Would the following work:<br/>(1) mount an Ubuntu LiveCD in a virtual DVD drive and choose 'Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer';<br/>(2) could I then mount the sda2 partition on the virtual hard drive with the following command `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` ?<br/>(3) format the sda2 partition with the following command `mkfs.ext4 -G 4096 /dev/sda2`<br/>(4) reinstall Ubuntu Server and manually select the (unchanged) sda1 partition and the (reformatted) sda2 partition<br/>(5)is there a way to make the Ubuntu Server installer use these partitions as-is without reformatting ?

Comment: Indeed you can make the required filesystem before you install to it. You may also be able to use `tune2fs` after the fact. Note that you do not mount a device before using `mkfs` - it will simply fail. There may also be an option using the "Advanced install" but I've never tried that.

Comment: Many thanks, so I'll skip mounting the partition. Will the Ubuntu instance launched from the LiveCD see the sda2 partition? Should I also wipe the sda1 partition with `mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sda1` ? Looking at the tunable filesystem parameters of the `tune2fs` command, there is a `-g` but not a `-G` option, so that probably won't work.

Comment: I see that `tune2fs` has a `flex_bg` parameter, but the documentation on [link]https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs says _"Tune2fs will not reorganize the location of the inode tables and allocation bitmaps, as mke2fs will do when it creates a freshly formated file system with flex_bg enabled"_

Comment: The LiveCD should see all available devices, and their partitions, no problem. I don't know what's on `/dev/sda1` so I can't honestly say what to do with that. I suspect it's a UEFI partition. Either way the new install will know what to do with it. For the sake of testing a VM though: you'd be fine with what you were using. Also note that Windows 10 has the Windows Subsystem for Linux which makes things easier, though it's not a full-fledged VM.

Comment: Indeed, sda1 is the boot partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ken guiding me in the right direction (thanks Ken!), I managed to solve the question. There may be a quicker or more professional way to do it, but the following steps worked for me:

1. Prepare a virtual disk as explained [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/best-practices-for-running-linux-on-hyper-v) and create a virtual machine using the previously created virtual disk as OS disk.
2. Mount the Ubuntu Server iso in a virtual DVD drive (set as first boot device) in the vm and start up the vm.
3. Install Ubuntu Server with the default options. In the filesystem setup step, choose 'Use an entire disk' (without setting up an LVM).
4. When the installation is finished and you login, you will notice that the installation procedure created 2 partitions: (1) /dev/sda1 : an uefi boot partition of 512 MB, formatted as fat32 and (2) /dev/sda2 : a system file partition occupying the rest of the disk space, formatted as ext4.
5. According to [Microsoft's recommendations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/best-practices-for-running-linux-on-hyper-v), the ext4 partition should be formatted prior to install with the 'number-of-groups' parameter set to 4096 (`mkfs.ext4 -G 4096 /dev/sda2`). To my knowledge, there is no opportunity to do so during the installation procedure. When we check the value of this parameter (`sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda2`) set by the default installation procedure, we see a value of 16 instead of 4096 (at the line called "Flex block group size"). We will solve this by mounting an Ubuntu LiveCD instance and reformatting the /dev/sda2 partition.
6. Poweroff the virtual machine and load the Ubuntu **Desktop** iso in its virtual DVD drive (set as first boot device).
7. Restart the vm and choose the option 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.
8. When the Ubuntu Desktop has loaded, open a terminal and execute `sudo mkfs.ext4 -G 4096 /dev/sda2`. This will wipe the partition and format it with the correct 'number-of-groups' parameter while leaving all other formatting parameters of that partition unchanged. Check this by running `sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda2` again.
9. Poweroff the live Ubuntu session (in my case, it froze when powering down and I had to kill the VM process in Task Manager), load the Ubuntu **Server** iso in its virtual DVD drive (set as first boot device) and restart the VM to go through the installation procedure again.
10. When getting to the filesystem setup, choose 'Custom storage layout' and hit 'Done'.
11. The next screen is asking you to: (1) 'Mount a filesystem at /' and to (2) 'Select a boot disk'.
12. First, select a boot disk by choosing the local disk, hitting enter and choosing 'Use As Boot Device' as so: [Step 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSsVE.png)
13. Second, select partition 2 already formatted as ext4, hit enter and choose 'Edit'.
14. In the dialog box, **ensure that under 'Format:' 'Leave formatted as ext4' is selected**. If not, the 'number-of-groups' parameter will be reset again to 16 and you'll have the pleasure of starting all over!
    [Step 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwijz.png)
15. Go to the 'Mount:' section in the same dialog box, hit enter and choose 'Other' as so: [Step 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YMjj.png)
16. You will get a message in red saying that this is the worst idea of your life and that your computer will auto-destruct in 30 seconds if you proceed: [Step 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THZTo.png). Be a rebel and hit 'Save' anyway.
17. You will now see that you have mounted a boot disk and a filesystem at /. Hit 'Done' and proceed with the default installation options.
18. When the installation is ready, login and execute `sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda2` again. If you've followed the previous steps, you should now see a value of 4096 at the line called "Flex block group size".

Enjoy your spanky new Ubuntu Server VM in Hyper-V!

Comment: You could save some time, don't need to install server 2x . After creating VM, boot first to Ubuntu Desktop - Try First, and you can even use Gparted or similar visual disk partitioning tool to create your partitions. Then turn off VM, change ISO to bootable server media, and continue. I am bit lazy to google (2AM), but there is probably way to jump to shell from inside Ubuntu server (visual) installer, then use fdisk and mkfs and other tools to make partitions manually (we know Windows has that secret menu, why wouldn't Ubuntu). But nice walkthrough, thanks!

Comment: I Googled after all, sure enough, not only can you jump to shell - you can even remote SSH into installer! So you can start installer, setup.network, and before disk section jump to shell or ssh and do fdisk and mkfs, then just continue installer. Read here for shell/ssh details.
 https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/general   When you try it, write us another nice walkthrough answer :)

Comment: You can use the integrated shell and you don't need the destop image.  Remove Step 6. Step 7 is Restart the machine and the install process and press F2 on the filesystem setup screen to get a shell. Step 8 is the same, Step 9 is enter 'exit' to leave the shell. from step 10 is the same

Answer (score 0):

There are comments in https://askubuntu.com/a/1235219/16819 that indicate that it is not necessary to install Ubuntu Server two times.

Unfortunately, with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS, that still seems to be necessary. It is not possible to run "sudo mkfs.ext4 -G 4096 /dev/sda2" after entering the "Try Ubuntu" mode without installing Ubuntu Desktop.

1. Make a Hyper-V disk using a PowerShell command:

```
New-VHD -Path C:\MyVHDs\test.vhdx -SizeBytes 127GB -Dynamic -BlockSizeBytes 1MB
```

2. Create a VM using the wizard and attach it to the VHD file.
3. Attach an Ubuntu ISO
4. Open the Settings dialog for the new VM.
5. Go to the Security section and choose the Microsoft UEFI Certificate Authority template to allow the Ubuntu boot media to install.
6. Turn on the computer
7. Install Ubuntu Desktop using the default options.
8. Shut down the computer.

Follow the same approximate steps as the  aforementioned answer starting at step 7.

Specific Instructions for Ubuntu Desktop:

1. Right-click on /dev/sda2
2. Change
3. Use as "Ext4 journaling file system". Do not check "Format the partition". Mount it as "/".
4. OK
5. Install Now
6. Click "Continue" on the scary pop up about backing up critical data. Similarly, click "Continue" on dialogs about changing or not changing the partition information.

If you try to get clever and run "sudo mkfs.ext4 -G 4096 /dev/sda" in "Try Ubuntu" mode prior to installing Ubuntu Desktop, then you will land at the following screen with no way to complete the installation.

[image: No way to install Ubuntu Desktop using the existing partition.]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).